# Github testing can't find file

Tags: python, github, pytest, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I have a "models" folder, inside which i have different models that are used for unit testing.
File hierarchy is as follows

```
- test
  - models
    - nn_class.sav
    - nn_reg.sav
  - test_model
```

I run test_model, which has unit test inside. And when i read the file `nn_class.sav`, it works perfectly fine by giving path `"./models"`. Whereas when i try to run the same tests on Github, it throws the error of **File not found**.
I have to use this instead, so it can find files in both environments.

```
model_name = 'nn_class.sav'
    if os.path.isdir('./models'):
        path = './models/'
    else:
        path = 'test/models/'
```

Is there a nice elegant way to deal with this issue. Someone suggested fixtures to me, i don't know if they'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not a neat way and better to avoid such tricks, but try to do

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
```

in the beginning of your `test_model` file, it will use root as run path for the case. then you can use relative path to the root. Or whatever folder, just change `.` to the path you need.

See comments to the reply here why it is better to avoid such tricks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/2957102